# Calculate the sum of three series which may be telescoping

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-2}{n!}$$
 $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+1}{n!}$$
 $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+n^2}}$$

I have to calculate their sums. So I guess they are telescoping. However, I've no idea about how to make the telescopy emerge.

Comment: Observe that $\frac{n-2}{n!} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} - \frac{2}{n!}$.

Comment: @MathNewbie But I need to get rid of the 2 to have a telescoping series

Comment: The first two are not telescoping in the traditional sense.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Why?

Comment: Because the $n$-th term cannot be written in a simple ways as $f(n)-f(n-1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Lets begin with the first two since they represent a very simple class. Consider the function

$$ e^x = 1 + x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{3!}x^3 + ...  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}{x^n}} $$

From here it suffices to consider

$$ \frac{e^x}{x^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}{x^{n-2}}} $$

And therefore

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{e^x}{x^2} \right] = \frac{e^x}{x^2}-2\frac{e^x}{x^3}  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{n-2}{n!}{x^{n-3}}}  $$

Let $x=  1$

$$ \frac{e^1}{1^2}-2\frac{e^1}{1^3} = -e =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{n-2}{n!}{1^{n-3}}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{n-2}{n!}}$$

But your sum starts from one so,

$$ -e - \frac{0-2}{0!} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n-2}{n!}} $$

Thus:

$$ 2 - e = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n-2}{n!}}$$

---

For the second one we pull the same technique instead by multiplying by $x$

$$\frac{d}{dx}[xe^x] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{n+1}{n!}{x^{n}}}  $$

$$e^x(1+x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{n+1}{n!}{x^{n}}} $$

$$2e = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{n+1}{n!}{1^{n}}} $$

$$2e-1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n+1}{n!} }$$

Comment: See @Tim Raczkowski's hint for the third one

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+n^2}}=\frac1{\sqrt n}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

Comment: Yep. You're right

Comment: For the second, note that $\frac{n+1}{n!}=\frac{1}{n!}+\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$

Summing from $n=1$ to infinity, the sum is $e-1+e=2e-1$

Done.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer that frogeyedpeas came up with.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Didn't see that...

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a general approach for formulas of the form:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n!}$$ where $f$ is a polynomial.It is determined by writing $f(x)$ in terms of the basis of $p_n(x)=x(x-1)\cdots(x-(n-1))$ (the so-called falling-factorial functions.)

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^m a_k p_k(x)$$

Then:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n!} = \left(\sum_{i=0}^m a_i\right)e$$

So $n-2= p_1(n)-2p_0(n)$ so:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n-2}{n!} = (1-2)e$$

and thus:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-2}{n!} = -e + 2$$

Answer (score 0):

The second one seems to be easy if we can use $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{%
n!}=e$$ as well known 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{n+1}{n!} &=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(\frac{n}{n!}+%
\frac{1}{n!}) \\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1}{n!}) \\
&=&\left( \sum_{m=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{m!}\right) +\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty
}\frac{1}{n!}\right) -1 \\
&=&e+e-1 \\
&=&2e-1.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I wish I could do the first one this easily. Any idead?

Comment: Could you edit your last comment (or add it to the answer)? The Latex is broken.

Comment: I put it as a new answer because latex broken!

Comment: The difference between the first one and the second one is that in the first you have +1 and in the second you have instead -2. If you have understand the technique you can compute with $+k (k>0)$ and with $-k (k>0)$. The same works!

Answer (score 0):

The first one can also be computed as the second one so easly
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{n-2}{n!} &=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(\frac{n}{n!}+%
\frac{-2}{n!}) \\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }(\frac{1}{(n-1)!}-2\frac{1}{n!}) \\
&=&\left( \sum_{m=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{m!}\right) +(-2)\left(
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n!}-1\right)  \\
&=&e+(-2)(e-1) \\
&=&2-e.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

We can compute the first series by splitting it into two parts.  The first part can be rearranged into a telescoping series while the second one is easily recognized.  To that end we write

$$\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{n-2}{n!}=\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{n!}-\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$$

The first series on the right can be written as the telescoping series

$$\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{n!}=\sum_1^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\frac{1}{n!}\right)=1$$

The second series is simply the Taylor Series for $e^1-1=e-1$.

Putting it all together we have

$$\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{n-2}{n!}=2-e$$

Comment: @user62029 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  As always, I just want to give you the best answer I can.